# Whats wrong with my C++ syntax here

Tags: c++

```
while input != 0
    { 
        if input == "r";
        cout << "Please input a floating point value for the height, and then a floating point value for the width, seperated by a comma." << endl;
        cin  >> height >> width;
    }
```

I am trying to write a basic program that takes the dimensions of basic shapes and outputs the  area.  This is what I am starting with, but I am not sure what is wrong with this syntax.  Could someone help?

Comment: Please pick up a book on C++ and read up on some of the basics. You're missing the parentheses around the condition expressions.

Comment: To help decide on a book see [The Definitive C++ Book Guide And List](http://tinyurl.com/so-cxxbooks).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The condition must be in parentheses. Here's your formatted code:

```
while (input != 0)
    { 
        if (input == "r")
        {
            cout << "Please input a floating point value for the height, and then a floating point value for the width, seperated by a comma." << endl;
            cin  >> height >> width;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also on the `if` statement.  And there almost certainly shouldn't be a semicolon after `if`.  And there needs to be a `main` function, header inclusions, and `namespace std` needs to be named somehow.  Variables need to be declared before use.  The program is an absolute disaster.

Comment: You probably want braces around the 'then' part of your `if` statement too.

Comment: You're right guys. I just pointed out the first error, but I added in the proper code for his statement. It appears this is just part of this code though, so I'm sure he must have a `main`/`namespace std`, or else the compiler must've told that.

Comment: Also, since `input` has no opportunity to change inside the loop, the loop either executes never or infinitely.  But that isn't a *syntax* error.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have your conditions surrounded by brackets and if needs to have code to execute if the condition is true its not a function call, so :

```
while (input != 0)
{ 
    if (input == "r"){
        cout << "Please input a floating point value for the height, and then a floating point value for the width, seperated by a comma." << endl;
        cin  >> height >> width;
    }
}
```

It also looks like your cin statement is wrong as well but without the rest of the code I don't know.

Comment: BlackJack is quicker than me, posted while I was typing.

Answer (score 0):

C++ parser/compiler isn't intelligent enough yet to understand what do you mean when you try to say

```
if input == "r"
when input != 0
```

compiler will get confused and won't be able to semantically understand your program. So you need to put parenthesis as mentioned in above answers.